# passing data from from an activiy to a fragment withn bottom navigation bar

Tags: java, android

I have created an application with a bottomNavigation bar which consists of 5 Fragments.The second fragment (Search fragment) consists of 1 TextView with setOnClickListener so once it is been licked  a layout activity will open on the top which includes a ListView to allow the user to select/click on a specific Item, so later on this selected item info should be displayed on that TextView within the(Search fragment).

I tried to use Bundle to pass data from but it doesn't work.

--------------------------MainActivity----------------------------------------

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



final Fragment f1 = new HomeFragment();
final Fragment f2 = new SearchFragment();
final Fragment f3 = new CameraFragment();
final Fragment f4 = new ChatFragment();
final Fragment f6 = new LogginFragment();

final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment active = f1;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    //the fragment
    BottomNavigationViewEx bnve = (BottomNavigationViewEx) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

    bnve.enableAnimation(false);
    bnve.enableShiftingMode(false);
    bnve.enableItemShiftingMode(false);
    bnve.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);


    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, f6, "6").hide(f6).commit();
    //fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, f5, "5").hide(f5).commit();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, f4, "4").hide(f4).commit();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, f3, "3").hide(f3).commit();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, f2, "2").hide(f2).commit();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, f1, "1").commit();

}


   public void MovetoSuccess(){

       startActivity(new Intent(this,SuccessActivity.class));
   }

  public void MovetoCategoiry(){

    startActivity(new Intent(this,Categories_Activity.class));
}


public BottomNavigationViewEx.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
        new BottomNavigationViewEx.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {

                    case R.id.nav_home:
                        fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(f1).commit();
                        active = f1;
                        return true;

                    case R.id.nav_search:
                        fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(f2).commit();
                        active = f2;
                        return true;
                    case R.id.nav_camera:
                        fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(f3).commit();
                        active = f3;
                        return true;
                    case R.id.nav_chat:
                        fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(f4).commit();
                        active = f4;
                        return true;
                    case R.id.nav_account:
                            fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(f6).commit();
                            active = f6;
                            return true;

                }



                return false;

            }
        };




  }
```

-------------------------- ---SearchFragment ---------------------------------

```
 public class SearchFragment extends Fragment  {


TextView Categories;


static boolean status = false;
String SelectedItem;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search,container,false);


    Categories = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.categories);

     Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();

          if (bundle != null){

        String SelectedItem = bundle.getString("ss");
        Categories.setText(SelectedItem);
    }


    Categories.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).MovetoCategoiry();

        }
    });



    return v;
}

public Boolean getifItemselected(Boolean status){
    this.status=status;
    return true;

    }


 }
```

--------------------------Categories_Activity---------------------------------

```
public class Categories_Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

ImageView BacktoMainPage;
ListView subCate;
public String selectedItem;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab_subcategory);
    subCate = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview_subcate);
    BacktoMainPage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.BacktoMain);
    BacktoMainPage.setOnClickListener(this);
    final SearchFragment sf = new SearchFragment();

    subCate.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
             selectedItem = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("ss",selectedItem);
            sf.setArguments(bundle);

            finish();

        }
    });

 }


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v == BacktoMainPage)
        finish();

         }


  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a Singleton like this

```
public class DataHolder {
//design pattern to share arguments between fragments and activities
private static DataHolder dataHolder = null;

private DataHolder() {
}

public static DataHolder getInstance() {
    if (dataHolder == null)
    {
        dataHolder = new DataHolder();
    }
    return dataHolder;
}


private  String item;

public String getItem() {
    return item;
}

public void setItem(String item) {
    this.item = item;
}
```

}

So to save your item use :

```
DataHolder.getInstance().setItem(selectedItem);
```

and to access your data use :

```
DataHolder.getInstance().getItem();
```

And this can help your to transfer your data between fragments and activities

Comment: Thanks a lot man it really works but i need to call the MainActivity class to refresh all the fragments so i used this code Intent in = new Intent(Categories_Activity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(in);

Comment: I got one question is there any way to refresh only that Search fragment

Comment: i guess i didn't get your question can you specify your needs ?

Comment: What I mean is that after I call the method DataHolder.getInstance.getItem to put that selected Item From the listview to the Textview field inside that Search fragment it won’t show unless I call the MainActivity (to start onCreat meth) hence it consists of the bottomNavigation bar with all fragments so fragments will be refreshed. So my question was is there any way to refresh that search fragment with out Calling the MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

You can  with the static list if user click the item of listview, you can add it in the list and use this list any fragment, or make a public class of setter getter to set and fetch value.

Comment: I tried as you said to use a public class with setters and getters, but it doesn't work because the Search fragment need to be refreshed!.

Comment: so try the public static list <String> because it will contain the value either you closed the application and when you refreshed your fragment then just clear the list.

Comment: would you please show me an example of code because I really didn't get it